# Storing restoring text upon rebuild of `TextEditor` in `LazyVStack`

Tags: swiftui

I'm using `LazyVStack` to list `TextEditor` objects. But it rebuilds while scrolling (as expected in Lazystacks) but I want to restore the text I was typing in each `Text Editor`. I'm thinking of using `objectIndex` and saving it to `String array` to save and retrieve the text. I don't wanna use `Non-Lazy` stacks. Any other better ideas to store and restore the text?

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct ContentView: View {
 
    @State private var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
               
                    ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { objectIndex in
                        
                        VStack {
                            
                            TextEditorObject (text: text)
                                 
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
      }
  
        }
    }
 
struct TextEditorObject: View {
 
    @State var text: String
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
             
                        
                        VStack {
                            
                            TextEditor (text: $text)
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .leading)
                                 
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: look-up using `ObservableObject` with something like, `@Published var textStore: [String] = [...]`, and use that in the 
`ForEach`.

Answer (score 0):

In TextEditorObject change @State var text: String to @Binding var text: String